# sklearn.metrics.roc_curve for multiclass classification

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, roc

I want to use [sklearn.metrics.roc_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) to get the ROC curve for multiclass classification problem. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) gives a solution on how to fit roc to multiclass problem. But I do not understand what the parameter "**y_score**" mean, what I should provide for this parameter in a multiclass classification problem.

Suppose a scenario like this. There are nine elements labeled from 0 to 8. The first three elements belong to group 0, the last three belong to group 2 and the three elements between belong to group1. 0, 3, 6 are the centers of the groups. I have a pairwise distance matrix. Then, what should I provide for the "y_score" parameter?

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

listTrue=[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2] #value j at index i means element i is in group j
y=label_binarize(y,classes=range(2))
#get distmatrix
#distmatrix[i][j] gives the distance between element i and element j
fpr=dict()
tpr=dict()
roc_auc=dict()

fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _=roc_curve(y.ravel(),y_score?)
roc_auc=auc(fpr["micor"], tpr["micro"])
```

Answer (score 0):

ROC is a means to evaluate the quality of a classifier. However, in your example there is just a ground truth of elements assigned to classes. Once you have a predictor, y_score could be the predicted probability that it belongs to the positive class.

Comment: I intend to use distance matrix to generate something like probablity. But what is y_score in multiclass problem? Because in the demo, there are 75 test samples and three classes, y_score is an array of shape (75,3). That is, I have to provide 3 values for one sample. Because I do not understand the svm part, so I do not know how it get y_score in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

**First I will answer your question about `y_score`. So, `y_score` in the example that you mentioned are the predicted (by the classifier) probabilities for the test samples. If you have 2 classes then `y_score` will have 2 columns and each of the columns will contain the probability of a sample to belong to this class.**

**To plot the multi-class ROC use `label_binarize` function and the following code. Adjust and change the code depending on your application.**

---

**Example using Iris data:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from itertools import cycle

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5, random_state=0)

classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                                 random_state=0))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
lw=2
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
colors = cycle(['blue', 'red', 'green'])
for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=2,
             label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
             ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic for multi-class data')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

In this example, you can print the `y_score`.

```
print(y_score)

array([[-3.58459897, -0.3117717 ,  1.78242707],
       [-2.15411929,  1.11394949, -2.393737  ],
       [ 1.89199335, -3.89592195, -6.29685764],
       .
       .
       .
```

[image]